# 13 method signatures of method append() in StringBuilder class but no short and no byte

Tags: java, append, stringbuilder

There are 13 method signatures of the StringBuilder method append() :

```
append(Object o) {...}
append(String str) {...}
append(StringBuffer sb) {...}
append(CharSequence s) {...}
append(CharSequence s, int start, int end)
append(char[] str) {...}
append(char[] str, int offset, int len) {...}
append(boolean b) {...}
append(char c) {...}
append(int i) {...}
append(long l) {...}
append(float f) {...}
append(double d) {...}
```

I noticed that byte and short are the only primitive data types missing from this list.
Although, using parameters of these types does work:

```
public static void main(String... unused) {
        short sh = 1;
        byte b = 2;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc").append(sh).append(b);
        System.out.println(sb);
        }
```

Output : abc12

**My question is why, or *how*, does this work?**

Is this because the compiler automatically promotes these parameters to int?

Comment: "Is this because the compiler automatically promotes these parameters to int?" Yes; this is the normal behaviour, after all. Did you similarly wonder why, for example, `charAt(byte)` is also missing?

Comment: Thanks. And actually, no i didn't wonder about that yet :-p.

Comment: Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void aMethod(int i)
{
    System.out.println("received "+i);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    short s=1;
    byte b=2;
    char c='c';
    aMethod(s);
    aMethod(b);
    aMethod(c);
}
```

They all use the `append(int)`.

See [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)